# Issue with the cursor data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue writing the code. Please help me.

I have a cursor c1 it will have some users and another cursor it will contain some other users.

c1 and c2 may have some common users.

I want to write code like this

```
if c1.user=c2.user
then 
insert into b1 table
else 
insert c1 into b1 table 
insert c2 into b2 table
end;
```

I think, I need to open cursors before if condition but if I open 2 cursors before if will it work? If not please suggest some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only operations that you're performing with the data in your cursor then there's no need for the cursor at all. JOIN the two cursor together and use a [multi-table insert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55088) with a WHEN clause

```
insert all
    into b1 (<columns> values (<values>)
  when c1.user is null or c2.user is null
    into b2 (<columns> values (<values>)
select <columns>
  from <some_table> c1
  full outer join <some_other_table> c2
    on c1.user = c2.user
 where <some_conditions>
```

By joining the two tables together with a FULL OUTER JOIN you SELECT everything from both tables, see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). You always insert into the table `B1` so there are no conditions but you only INSERT into `B2` when the users are different and so would use a WHEN clause. If they're different one or the other will be NULL as they won't have fulfilled the JOIN condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to do more validations in else block and I need to use only cursors and plsql programming